# Getting undefined as the value for span tag while traversing a table

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

I need to reach the the span tag with `class = ustatus` and have the jQuery object obtained for `id = foo`.

```
<tr>
  <td> <input name = 'user' type='radio 'id='foo'/> </td>
  <td> <input id='boo'/> </td>
  <td> <input id='too'/> </td>
  <td> <input id='yoo'/> </td>
  <td> <span class='ustatus'> Active </span> </td>
</tr>
```

I was trying like:

```
$("input[name = 'user']:checked").closest('td').find('.ustatus').first().val()
```

but get `undefined` as the value. Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few Issues in your code:

1) You need to traverse to tr instead of td. as span lies in one of the sibling td of selected radio buttons parent td

2) span element have text/html property associated to it and not value.you need to use `.text()`/`.html()` instead of `.val()`

3) as there is only one ustatus element in tr, you do not need `.first()` selector.

```
$("input[name='user']:checked").closest('tr').find('.ustatus').text()
```

Comment: Why can't I reach `span` from `td`? Why do I need to reach `tr` first and then travel to span?

Comment: @SuhailGupta `as span lies in one of the sibling td of selected radio buttons parent td`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
$("input[name = 'user']:checked").closest('tr').find('.ustatus:first').text()
```

Because,`ustatus` is the sibling of your parenent `td`. So you need to traverse to the parent `tr` first. Then you can use the `find()` method, which will search for the child elements

Comment: What difference does it make? Could you elaborate.

Comment: I already explained it in the answer. Your ustatus is not the child of current parent td.

Answer (score 0):

> span has no value you need to use text() or html()

`var text = $("input[name = 'user']:checked").parent().parent().find('.ustatus').text();`

or

`var html = $("input[name = 'user']:checked").parent().parent().find('.ustatus').html() ;`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2mueybzs/)

Because your anchor is the input you need to go 2 level up to `tr` where you can find the `td` that has the class `.ustatus` so you need to add 2 `parent()`

Answer (score 0):

You are targetting the  cell and then trying to find ".ustatus" class of first order to take the html content/value, using val()

```
$("input[name = 'user']:checked").closest('td').find('.ustatus').first().val()
```

`val()` is used to get values of form fields.
Use either `text()` or `html()` to get plain text content or including tags respectively.

```
$("input[name ='user']:checked").closest('tr').find('.ustatus:first').text()
```

would work as we are finding `.ustatus:first` in  row and taking the content using `text()`.